# Error at 'END' when trying to create event in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm trying to create an event with the following query:

```
CREATE 
    EVENT `delete_messages` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR STARTS '2018-09-20 00:00:00'
    DO BEGIN    
        DELETE FROM `messages`
    END
```

The error it is giving me is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to place a semicolon at the end of DELETE statement

```
delimiter |

CREATE 
    EVENT `delete_messages` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR STARTS '2018-09-20 00:00:00'
    DO BEGIN    
        DELETE FROM `messages`;
    END |

delimiter ;
```

If not so then you can try your query without BEGIN and END:

```
CREATE 
EVENT `delete_messages` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR STARTS '2018-09-20 00:00:00'
DO
    DELETE FROM `messages`;
```